# Meteor app fails to run - Object #<Compiler> has no method 'host'

Tags: javascript, meteor

### Info

- Creating a new app via `meteor create app_name` and running it works fine
- Trying to run an app that another developer is working on - it works on his machine
- Have tried totally reinstalling meteor

#### Error Log

```
/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
        throw(ex);
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Compiler> has no method 'host'
at Compiler.visit (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/css-stringify/lib/compiler.js:33:25)
at Compiler.mapVisit (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/css-stringify/lib/compiler.js:45:17)
at Compiler.stylesheet (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/css-stringify/lib/identity.js:43:15)
at Compiler.compile (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/css-stringify/lib/identity.js:35:15)
at Object.module.exports [as stringifyCss] (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/css-stringify/index.js:35:25)
at [object Object]._.extend.mergeCss (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1077:35)
at [object Object]._.extend.make (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:503:12)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2054:14
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2099:20
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2098:7
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:264:13
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:257:29
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:255:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:246:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at Object.capture (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:19)
at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2040:31)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:554:24
at time (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/profile.js:231:28)
at Function.run (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/profile.js:377:12)
at bundleApp (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:544:34)
at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:591:35)
at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:821:28)
at /Users/USERNAME/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:402:12
```

Not sure where to go from here. Any help?

Comment: It seems like the "another developer is working on", have some package, that you are missing, did you `git clone` the project? did you create a new `meteor create project` and just copy the files? the `meteor list` are equals? maybe some npm package.

Comment: git cloned, then tried recreating, then wiped it all and had him zip up his project, and then even his `~/.meteor` folder. What worked in the end is totally wiping everything, having him recreate, then recloning. Just one of those things - who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the other day. Turns out it was a `node_modules` directory I had sitting around from experimenting with some NPM modules. Removing the directory got rid of the error.